# CentOS 7 can't ping from server

Tags: networking, centos, ip, ping, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having a Strange issue with CentOS 7. I have my server setup with 2 NICs a private network and a public network. I'm able to ping the server on both the private and public IP. But I cannot ping FROM the server any public IP. What's strange is that I could access the public network from the server (curl public sites, download files, etc..) but I cannot ping out. However, I could ping other servers on the same private network.

I have tried to stop firewalld but that wasn't the issue. I have other servers with similar config running CentOS 6 and I've never encountered this problem.

So this works:

-From a remote machine:

ping my server ip

ping my server internal ip

-From the server

ping another server internal ip

Doesn't work:

-From the server

ping any public ip

ping server public ip gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a routing problem.. All my traffic was being routed through the internal NIC so I couldn't ping any public IPs.